# How to create inner table with PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working with PDFBox using Java

I need to create nested tables. If anybody have any idea on how to create please help with it.

[The table need to somewhat like this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPkvl.png)

Thanks in Advance

Could not find any resources related to it

Comment: You surely are aware that PDFBox by itself does only offer lowlevel drawing primitives like drawing short text strings or vector graphics. For drawing tables you either have to layout all these pieces manually or use some third-party layouting libraries, see [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#can-i-use-pdfbox-to-create-complex-layouts%3F). Have you tried whether such third-party libraries support nested tables?